# Using a Radial basis function with back propagation in c# using Encog library

Tags: c#, neural-network, encog

I have created a simple RBF network with a gaussian function by using,

```
RBFNetwork newNetwork = new RBFNetwork(28,14,1,RBFEnum.Gaussian);
```

I need to create a RBF Network with back propagation having 28 inputs and only one output giving 0 or 1 as a result.
I could not proceed further in training it with data sets.
Help needed.

Comment: hey @najus can you share with me the code of RBFNetwork? I could not find any example of usage.

Comment: @murt Let me see. It was a long time back so not sure where it is. If i find it,  I will get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

I think your answer lies here..
http://massapi.com/class/org/encog/neural/rbf/RBFNetwork.java.html
Hope this helps You..Though it is in java u can understand the logic behind it

Comment: Thanks for your help but I needed it in c#. I will try to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `EncogUtility.TrainConsole()`, `EncogUtility.TrainToError()` or `EncogUtility.TrainDialog()` methods, if you don't want to make your own stopping strategy.

See [EncogUtility](http://www.heatonresearch.com/javadoc/encog-2.3/org/encog/util/simple/EncogUtility.html) for Javadocs, C# ones are close to. The only thing is that it uses not SCG internally but `ResilientPropagation`.

To construct a dataset you must have `double[][]` inputs and `double[][]` desired outputs of the same size and in the same order. Then the code looks so:

```
var trainingSet = new BasicMLDataSet(inputs, outputs);
EncogUtility.TrainConsole(network, trainingSet, 10 /*minutes training*/);
```